# I selected 2 tables for order and customer but I add calendar to monitor the sales from specific dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

I successfully did this first query but the 2nd query won't work

```
select order_id, firstname, lastname, phone, address, product, price, qty, subtotal, downpayment, total
from order_item, order_user on order_user.id = order_item.order_id
```

I tried this but it won't work

```
select order_id, firstname, lastname, phone, address, product, price, qty, subtotal, downpayment, total
from order_item, order_user
where order_user.id = order_item.order_id  where date >= '" + startdate.ToString() + "' AND date <= '" + enddate.ToString() + "'
```

Comment: Never concatenate parameter values, use named parameters.

Comment: You should be using proper join syntax, not this old style syntax.

Comment: The second `where` should be `and`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are using where twice in the query statement. That is not allowed. Also, note that the date format used for comparison is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

The query below should solve your problem:

```
select order_id, firstname, lastname, phone, address, product, price, qty, subtotal, downpayment, total
from order_item, order_user
where order_user.id = order_item.order_id and date >= '2020-06-05' and date <= '2020-06-14'
```

It seems like you are generating the query in your c# code.

For creating the query in C#, you can use the below code:

```
string query = @"select order_id, firstname, lastname, phone, address, product, price, qty, subtotal, downpayment, total
from order_item, order_user
where order_user.id = order_item.order_id and date >= '" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and date <= '" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
```